# The network icon in debian system taskbar is missing

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, networkmanager, kvm

Operating System: Debian Bookworm stable

Desktop Environment: Xfce

I have Debian with all the latest updates installed. After installing software like qemu-system, virt-manager, and bridge-utils, ***I disconnected both the wired and Wi-Fi connections***. When I use "sudo virsh net-start default" to enable KVM's default network, the network icon in the Debian system tray disappears (it becomes a blank space), and network status notifications are no longer present. However, when I use "sudo virsh net-destroy default" to disable KVM's default network, a notification pops up (***The network connection has bee disconnected***), and the Debian system tray network icon reappears, along with the network status notifications.

In other words, simply enabling KVM's default network causes the Debian system tray network icon to disappear. Disabling KVM's default network allows the network icon in the Debian system tray to reappear, and network notifications return to normal.

Although the network icon appears blank, clicking on it with the mouse brings up the network configuration interface (which includes Wi-Fi and VPN settings). Additionally, right-clicking at that location with the mouse reveals the "Connection information" option. Clicking on "Connection information" opens a dialog displaying information about virbr0 configuration. However, when I disable KVM's default network, the "Connection information" option is grayed out and cannot be accessed.

Whether I enable or disable KVM's default network, the output of "brctl show" remains the same, as shown below:

```
bridge name        bridge id          STP enabled      interfaces
  virbr0        8000.525400a3ca91        yes
```

Even after reinstalling the Debian system and KVM software, the same issue occurs. Enabling KVM's default network leads to the disappearance of the Debian system tray network icon. Disabling it restores normal functionality.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: I found a post from years ago that was in the same situation as I was experiencing and can give you a reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597958/is-it-normal-that-network-manager-manages-virbr0